# Using PaperJS exclude boolean operation to create interactive overlapping shapes

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I am looking to understand how to dynamically move shapes around the canvas and when they intersect to exclude their overlap. I have repurposed PaperJS's [Boolean Operations Example](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/) to achieve this but I don't quite understand the reason behind it... Here is my [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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): I have a couple questions hopefully someone can help me with.

1. Why do I need to group the objects and hide them from the DOM?
2. Why does the `moveBelow()` function rerender the shapes on the canvas? Without calling the `moveBelow()` function the shapes aren't visible on the canvas, but in order to do that I need to call it on an object that I am not actually using.
3. Is there a way to make this work so if you have more than two shapes, any two shapes that overlap perform the operation?